# determine whether the following are surjective homomorphisms and if so are they also isomorphisms by computing kernels

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

So I am looking to determine whether the following are surjective homomorphisms, and if so are they also isomorphisms by computing kernels:

I am completely new to the topic of kernels in group theory so I apologize if this doesn't make much sense. I really need help understanding these questions.

1) $G = \mathbb R, H = ((0,∞),×), f(x) = e^x$,

2) $G = H = \mathbb R, f(x) = 2x$

3) $G = (\mathbb C/{0} ,×), H = S^1, f(z) = \frac{z}{|z|}$

4) $G = O(n), H = \mathbb Z_2, f(A) = \det(A)$

5) $G = H = ((0,\infty),×), f(x) = x^2$

**My attemp:t**

1) We have $e^{x+y}=e^x*e^y=e^xe^y$ so $e^x$ is a homomorphism,

and the kernel $e=({x \in \mathbb R : e^x = e_{(0, \infty)}=1})=({0})$.

So $e^x$ is injective and hence an isomorphism.

2) $f(xy)=2(xy)$ which is not equal to $2x*2y$.

Hence it is not a homomorphism.

3) Really unsure how this works.... $f(zx)=\frac{zx}{|zx|}?$

4) $f(AB)=\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. Hence it is a homomorphism....

I'm not sure how to compute the kernel.

5) $f(xy)=(xy)^2=x^2y^2=f(x)*f(y)$. Hence this is a homomorphism;

the kernel would be $({x \in (0,\infty)|x^2 = (0,\infty)^2=1})$ (this doesn't look like it makes any sense).

Comment: For (2), the group operation should be addition ($\mathbb R$ is not a group under multiplication), hence you want to check whether $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$.

Comment: @Bungo Thanks so much. It would therefore be a homomorphism

Comment: For (3), you can continue: $$\frac{zx}{|zx|} = \frac{zx}{|z||x|} = \frac{z}{|z|}\frac{x}{|x|} = f(z)f(x).$$For (4), is it true that only the identity matrix has determinant $1$? For (5), the kernel is the set of all positive real numbers $x$ such that $x^2 = 1$. What values of $x$ satisfy this?

Comment: @Bungo I would have assumed yes. But should I think about subgroups here ?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Having multiple questions in the same post is discouraged and such posts may be closed, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).